Interpretation and expression for the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in Laurent series about a non-singular point
If we expand a function about a pole, then the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in  the $1/z$ term is the residue of the function at the pole $z=z_0$ which can be simply calculated even without doing the Laurent series expansion via the formula $$\mathrm{Res}(f(z),z_0)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\mathrm{lim}_{z\to z_0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left[ (z-z_0)^n f(z)\right]$$. What if we expand the function about a regular point? Since the regular point is obviously not a pole, I cannot use the above formula for residues. Is there a simple formula for calculating $a_{-1}$ in this case apart from the integral formulas from Laurent's theorem itself. If that is not a residue, what could be an interpretation of $a_{-1}$ in that case?
Note that $a_{-1}$ is zero in the disk $|z|<r$ where $r$ is the distance to the nearest singularity. I am asking for $|z|>r$ where $a_{-1} \ne 0$ but the Laurent series is still convergent.

The formula for the residuum is wrong. The function $(z-z_0)^nf(z)$ should be differentiated. The formula holds if $z_0$ is a pole of order $n.$ In $|z|>a$ a similar formula holds if $f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^na_kz^k,$ $a_n\neq 0,$ i.e. $0$ is a pole of order $n$ for $f(1/z).$

Oops. That was a typo: now corrected. I couldn't understand the last two sentences of your comment. Does this also hold for the corrected formula? I want to understand the meaning of $a_{-1} $ for a Laurent series which is expanded about a regular point.

Are you assuming the function is holomorphic for $|z|>a$ ?

Yes, that's correct.

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic for $|z|>a>0.$ Then the function $g(z):=f(z^{-1})$ is holomorphic in $0<|z|<a^{-1}.$
Hence  $$g(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty b_kz^k\quad (*)$$ Thus $$f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty b_kz^{-k}$$ We have $a_{-k}=b_{k}.$ We can calculate $a_{-1}=b_1$ with the formula similar to the one in OP provided that $b_n=0$ for some $k\le n$ and $b_{n}\neq 0.$ Then basing on $(*)$ we get $$a_{-1}=b_1={ 1\over (n+1)!}\lim_{z\to 0}{d^{n+1}\over dz^{n+1}}(z^ng(z))\\ ={1\over (n+1)!}\lim_{z\to 0}{d^{n+1}\over dz^{n+1}}(z^nf(z^{-1})) $$

So $a_{-1}$ is the residue at the pole of $f(\frac{1}{z})$ at $z=0$?

No, it is a residue of $z^{-2}f({1\over z}).$
